# Why do I keep getting pbu as a message in the console whenever I run a command in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I've been using Rstudio to do some schoolwork. I've had no problems with it, but I've noticed that everytime I run a command the console returns the result plus a message saying pbu

#4
x<- 1:10

For example for that, the console gives me:

[image: console]

What does it mean? It doesn't seem to affect my answers in any way that I can tell, and it happens with every command I give the console.

Thanks!

I've tried looking up pbu but I've gotten nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What does `ls()` show when you first open an R session?, i.e. done no homework yet.

Comment: It's strange. One possible explanation could be that you accidentally typed pbu into your console and left it there. Try clearing the console to see if that resolves the issue. Just a suggestion!

Comment: I suspect you tiped "pbu" in the console but did not run this command (did not press ENTER). Then you ran several code lines from the source pane. This prints the outputs from these commands but keeps the "pbu" in the prompt. Try cleaning the prompt by pressing ESCAPE